# How to set the execution date same as the trigger time?

Tags: airflow

I'm just learning Apache Airflow. I understand that the execution date is not the same time as the actual time a dag run is triggered.

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.

> Let’s Repeat That The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Yeah, For a daily job, cron jobs run at the start of the day; Airflow jobs run at the end of the day.

I humbly ask: Anyway to set the execution date same as the trigger time?

Comment: Define trigger time and execution time in the question

Answer (score 0):

You generally structure your tasks such that you'll provide a date to the job via kwargs (for idempotency, etc).

Airflow provides macros (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) that expose both the `data_interval_start` and the `data_interval_end`.

I believe you're looking for the `data_interval_end` which aligns with the logical date that the job is running.

Answer (score 0):

seems we just have to use `{{ next_execution_date }}` or `data_interval_end` - the next execution date template, which is actually the real execution_date ((.
Unless they will implement some Dag's parameter to allow triggering it on data interval's start.